# Узнать пиксельную позицию символа в div.contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Суть в следующем, допустим этот текст находится в div -

```
привет привет привет 
привет @привет привет
```

как узнать позицию от левого верхнего угла div-a, top и left знака "@" в пикселях?

Comment: а зачем это нужно?

Comment: В принципе, повторение facebook реализации ссылки на юзера, упоминание о юзере в комментарии

Comment: Вопрос уже обсуждался на stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23526970/1941460, реализация работает без доп. обертки в `span`.

Comment: @Павел Азанов Немного не то, подобную реализацию уже делал, вопрос в том что бы реализовать не перемещая каретку, пользователь поставил "@" и пишет за ней - "Иван В" и под "@" появляется autocomlete по совпадениям - подобное уже есть на fb.com

Comment: @sivik_xes, на самом деле перемещать каретку не обязательно, при наборе `@` каретка стоит в нужном месте, запоминаются ее координаты минус ширина символ `@`. Как-то так

Comment: Так же продумывал такой вариант, но дело в том что этих @ может быть несколько, и пользователь может кликнуть в текст другой @ до этого находившись в преждней

Comment: @sivik_xes, ну тут уже все зависит от координат по которым кликнули

Comment: @Grundy Ну да, или кликнули, или же стрелками на клавиатуре переместились, но например "@"Иван Иванов - курсор может быть в любом месте этих 2 слов, а позиционировать нужно относительно @

Comment: @sivik_xes, тут важно же просто отследить позицию курсора, позиционирование же идет только один раз, при открытии, после того как дополнение открылось, его расположение не меняется

Comment: @Grundy не много не верно, нужно отследить позицию знака "@". курсор может быть в тексте за этим символом

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43340/discussion-between-grundy-and-sivik-xes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На основе ответа на [английский вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23526667/javascript-how-to-get-caret-offset-from-start-of-content-editable-div-with-mult/23526970#23526970) можно узнавать текущее положение курсора, при вводе проверять что именно ввели, если ввели нужны символ - получать координаты курсора и показывать по ним попап.

При клике так же проверять координаты курсора и вычислять нужно ли показывать попап.

В примере ниже попап показывается, если курсор не далее чем в 5 позициях правее символа `@`.

Пример очень простой, и возможно потребует доработок для использования.

```js
var popup = document.querySelector('#popup');

function getCurrentRange() {
  var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
  range.setStart(range.startContainer, Math.max(0, range.startOffset - 1));
  return range;
}

function showPopupAt(range, distance) {
  range.setStart(range.startContainer, Math.max(0, range.startOffset - (distance || 0)));
  range.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset + 1);
  var rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
  popup.style.display = 'block';
  popup.style.left = rect.left + 'px';
  popup.style.top = rect.bottom + 'px';
}

function hidePopup() {
  popup.style.display = 'none';
}

function toggleByDistance(range) {
  var prev = range.startContainer.textContent.lastIndexOf('@', range.startOffset);
  var distance = prev != -1 ? range.startOffset - prev : -1;
  if (distance < 0 || distance > 5) { //for example
    hidePopup();
  } else {
    showPopupAt(range, distance);
  }
}
document.querySelector('[contenteditable]').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  var range = getCurrentRange()
  if (e.key == '@') {
    showPopupAt(range);
  } else {
    toggleByDistance(range);
  }
});
document.querySelector('[contenteditable]').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  toggleByDistance(getCurrentRange());
});
```

```css
[contenteditable] {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
#popup {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px lightgray;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable></div>
<div id="popup">
  <div>123</div>
  <div>234</div>
  <div>345</div>
  <div>456</div>
  <div>567</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Условия отображения у меня немного другие, но тем не менее смогу поправить этот код под свои нужды, огромное Спасибо!

Comment: Красота, великолепно)

Answer (score 8):

Решением в лоб может быть оборачивание символа `@` например в `span` и взятие его смещения.

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var editor = document.querySelector("[contenteditable]");
  var html = editor.innerHTML;
  editor.innerHTML = html.replace(/@/, "<span>$&</span>");
  document.getElementById('coord').innerHTML = document.querySelector('span').offsetLeft + ' ' + document.querySelector('span').offsetTop;
  editor.innerHTML = html
});
```

```css
[contenteditable] {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable>
  привет привет привет привет @привет привет
</div>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="GetCoord" />
<div id="coord"></div>
```

Comment: span явно лишний, с таким же успехом можно было бы поставить курсор перед @, считать позицию, и после этого вернуть курсор на место, снова таки несколько действий, а хотелось бы как можно легче реализацию

Comment: @sivik_xes, да, как вариант, по другому сделать не получится, текст не рассматривается как самостоятельная единица в скрипте, поэтому нельзя узнать простым запросом например координаты третьего символа во второй строке в тексте элемента. То есть в любом случае будут либо расчеты, либо незаметное оборачивание и разворачивание и получения координаты конкретного элемента, а не символа в тексте

Comment: в таком случае даже не знаю, мне не верится, что нельзя, буду по возможности дальше копать.

Comment: @sivik_xes а надо верить =)

Comment: @Василий Барбашев очень позитивный настрой, нужно верить что есть что-то невозможное), еще скажите, что нельзя убрать желтый background при автозаполнении в chrome)

Comment: @sivik_xes надо верить!)))) Не, ну так то нет нерешаемых задач. Дело в подходе. Я просто не вижу проблемы в описанном вами. Найти ближайшую @ при клике в поле и отпозиционироваться? и? событие onClick выдаст `e.offsetX, e.offsetY` позиции клика внутри поля

Comment: @Василий Барбашев - видите в чем дело, я на это 2 рабочих дня убил, и сделал более простую реализацию, а хотелось бы эту, которую описал выше, если же вы не видите сложности - то пожалуйста реализуйте, буду вам очень благодарен, а так же отдам 100 балов за это решение.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант вы можете попробовать использовать [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range), который поддерживается всеми современными [браузерами](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range#Browser_compatibility).

```
<div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur excepturi laudantium nihil officia totam. @Distinctio dolorem earum fugiat hic illum maiores natus perferendis possimus quod similique sint, temporibus voluptas voluptatum?
</div>

<script>
    var contentEl = document.querySelector('.content');

    var textEl      = contentEl.childNodes[0];
    var textContent = textEl.textContent;
    var index       = textContent.indexOf('@');

    var range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(textEl, index);
    range.setEnd(textEl, index + 1);

    var rects  = range.getClientRects();
    var offset = {
        top: rects[0].top - contentEl.offsetTop,
        left: rects[0].left - contentEl.offsetLeft
    };

    console.log(offset);
</script>
```